# PHP/HTML: Quote inside a quote inside a quote

Tags: php

I'm having trouble creating the mouseover and mouseout states of the image because I have a quote inside a quote inside a quote. Is when I use the PHP code below I receive an Uncaught SyntaxError because the " before $id is closing the entire line. Any ideas how to get around this? Thanks!

```
<img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '_1medium.jpg" onmouseover="this.src=\'inventory_images/\" . $id . \"_2medium.jpg\';" onmouseout ="this.src=inventory_images/" . $id . "_1medium.jpg;" />
```

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Are you in a PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Look into String Interpolation over Concatenation when using simple data. All you have to do is surround the variable in `{}` curly braces. You also left off a `;`.

```
<img src="inventory_images/{$id}_1medium.jpg" 
    onmouseover="this.src='inventory_images\{$id}\_2medium.jpg';" 
    onmouseout ="this.src='inventory_images\{$id}\_1medium.jpg';" />
```

The path may not be correct I assumed `inventory_images\id\image` you can just remove the `\` between id and underscore if needed with out modifying anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case anyone else has this same issue here was my fix.

```
<img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '_1medium.jpg" onmouseover="this.src=\'inventory_images/' . $id . '_2medium.jpg\';" onmouseout ="this.src=\'inventory_images/' . $id . '_1medium.jpg\';"/>
```